# Changing Part of a Pandas Dataframe from a Function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a GUI (using kivy) that in part manipulates a Dataframe. One of the pieces of it is to have a button call a function. This function will increment a value in the Dataframe. However, I can't get it to work. I believe it has to do with the function altering the passed value, and not the memory that it came from. Here's an example of what I'm getting at:

```py
def change(thing, new):
    thing = new

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a" : [1 ,3],
     "b" : [2, 4]})
print(df)
>>>    a  b
    0  1  2
    1  3  4

change(df.at[0, 'a'], 7)
print(df)
>>>    a  b
    0  1  2
    1  3  4

df.at[0, 'a'] = 7
print(df) 
>>>    a  b
    0  7  2
    1  3  4
```

`.loc` and `.at` all alter a Dataframe as expected outside of a function. I'm unsure how to change it from a function. In case it's of use, here are some (simplified) chunks of the actual code I'm working with to hopefully clarify my intentions:

```py
def cell(value):
    entry = TextInput(text=str(value))

    def increment_up(value, instance):
        value += 1
        entry.text = str(value)

    button_up = Button(text='up', 
                       on_release=partial(increment_up, value))

    layout_buttons.add_widget(button_up)
```

Above, I'm trying to create a 'cell' that a has a text field and up-button. When the up button is pressed, it should increment the `value`. It comes into play like this e.g. `my_layout.add_widget(cell(df.loc[i, 'Times']))`

Comment: What do you think that got passed to `change(df.at[0, 'a'], 7)`?

Comment: @cs95 They are the same type. So either both float, or both int as far as examples go. I'll add to the post a snippet of the actual thing I'm working on for a concrete reference.

Comment: Why don't you define a function with 4 arguments: df, row_idx, col_idx, and value_to_set? Then inside the function you'd just need to to `df.at[row_idx, col_idx] = value_to_set` and you're done.

Comment: df.at actually returns a value, but the "=" operator is overridden to behave in cetain a way, so when you actually pass df.at to a function, you are passing the value at the given row,column, you can check that by printing "thing" inside change

Comment: @cs95 Oh I didn't think of that! Do you mind if I post an answer using that for the example?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cs95. Rather than trying to change an argument in a function, with the intent of changing part of a dataframe we feed to it as said-argument, we have the function change a piece of a dataframe, that we specify through arguments. Please excuse my very nontechnical explanation.

```py
def change2(df, row, col, new):
    df.at[row, col] = new

my_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a" : [1 ,3],
     "b" : [2, 4]})

change2(my_df, 0, 'a', 7)
print(my_df)
>>>    a  b
    0  7  2
    1  3  4
```